# Fair distribution

Tags: average

I have an user, who received one score in 3 different things for example in `A`, `B` and `C`.

I want to get what average score received user for each thing.  `1/3 = 0.33` so, this is fair distribution, but `0.33+0.33+0.33` is not `1`.

May be give to `A` `0.34` score (suppose `A` is first thing and it has priority) and others `0.33`, in this case sum will be 1, but this is a little unfair distribution.

Which case is better and logical in this situation? maybe you can offer some better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1/3 = 0.33$ is not true. $1/3 = 0.33333333333333333333\dots$

Simply set the average score recieved to $\frac13$ precisely, and then it will be fair.